# Angular 6 - Waiting for element to load inside *ngIf on setting ngIf to true

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using angular 6.

I have a html like the below.

```
<div class="catalog-menus-subnav-wrapper"
                     *ngIf="showMenus">
 <div class="hidden-elem">
 </div>
</div>
```

Here, showMenus will be false by default and setting this to true on click of a button in the same page.

Now, I am trying to get this div in angular immediately after setting showMenus to true and not getting sometimes as the dom is not loaded completely.

```
public onClick(event) {

      this.showMenus= true;

      const item= $(event.currentTarget);
      const wrapper = item.next('.catalog-menus-subnav-wrapper');
      const height= item.closest('.hidden-elem').height();

  }
```

Here, item.next('.catalog-menus-subnav-wrapper') not returning values sometimes as the DOM load is not done while this is executed. Is there any way to wait for DOM to load after setting showMenus to true? Or, Is there any other fix?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting the data inside the menu with a service through a http or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **hidden**, If you use **ngIf** then it will remove element from DOM

Try this below,

in `.html`

```
<div class="catalog-menus-subnav-wrapper" [hidden]="!showMenus">
   <div class="hidden-elem">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it work if i have 2 conditions like, [hidden]="showMenus && selecetdLevel == menu.level"

Comment: hidden is opposite from ngIf, means "ngIf = "showMenus == false" then it is hide and if  [hidden]="showMenus == false" it will display element...Keep in mind this scenario

Comment: This can have some perfomance issues, since you are  loading the div but hidding it, what about if the data takes longer than expected to arrive and the user tries to show the menu it will show empty